# Geometric interpretation of the solution to PDE $u_x + yu_y =0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The equation $u_x + yu_y =0$ has the general solution $u(x,y)=f(ye^{-x}).$

The characteristic curves should look like

[image]

I tried to plot the solution using google. Is this  plot correct?  shouldn't be $u$ constant alongside each of the characteristic curve? It is not on this plot: [link](https://www.google.ie/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=y*e%5E(-x))

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u_x+yu_y=0$$
FIRST PART, Solving with the method of characteristics :

From $\quad 1u_x+yu_y=0 u \quad$ the set of characteristic equations is :
$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{0}$$
because the coefficient of $u_x$ is $1$ , the coefficient of $u_y$ is $y$ and the coefficient of $u$ is $0$ .

From $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{y}$ the equation of the set of characteristic curves is $\ln|y|-x=$constant, or :
$$ye^{-x}=c_1$$
To be finite $\frac{du}{0}$ implies $u=$constant. So, the equation of the set of characteristic curves is :
$$u=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE expressed on implicit form is :
$$F\left(ye^{-x} \:,\: u\right)=0$$
where $F$ is any differentiable function of two variables.

Solving this implicit equation for the second variable leads to the explicit form :
$$u=f(ye^{-x})$$
where $f$ is any differentiable function.

SECOND PART, answer to the question of graphical interpretation :

I suppose that your graph represents the set of characteristic curves 
$$y=c_1e^x$$
drawn with various values of $c_1$

On the characteristic curve corresponding to $c_1$ :
$$u=f(ye^{-x})=f(c_1)$$
since $c_1$ is a constant, $f(c_1)$ is constant, so $u$ is constant.
$$u=f(c_1)=c_2$$

Thus $u(x,y)$ is constant all along the characteristic curve considered.

But $u(x,y)$ isn't constant if the point $(x,y)$ goes from one curve $(c_1)$ to another curve $(c'_1)$, because $u(x,y)$ varies from $f(c_1)=c_2$ to $f(c'_1)=c'_2$ which are different.

Comment: I don't get the last part, does the absolute value of y $ln|y|$ determine here two cases of the solution, which lead to the "split" of the surface representing the solution?   looking at the plot it doesn't look like the u(x,y) stays on the same level along the characteristic curves and this confuses me

Comment: There is no two cases of the solution. The ODE is $dx=\frac{dy}{y}$ which general solution is $ye^{-x}=c_1$. Don't worry about the $\ln$ which is only an intermediate step in the solving of the ODE. If this confuses you, solve the ODE first for $x>0$ and second for $x<0$, both together give $ye^{-x}=c_1$. The drawing of the characteristic curves is made with the equation $y(x)=c_1e^x$ which comes from $ye^{-x}=c_1$.

Comment: The drawing of $z=ye^{-x}$ doesn't represent the characteristic curves : it represents a particular case of $u(x,y)$. So, it's not a convenient representation to understand what are the characteristics curves.